# Prove that the set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the set $M=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \leq \alpha \}$ where $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  1&x\leq 1\\2&x > 1\end{cases}$$ is closed.

So I must consider $\alpha$ as an arbitrary number, I divided it up in 3 cases. Case 1 is whenever $\alpha \geq 2$, case 2 is when $1 \leq \alpha < 2$ and case 3 is when $\alpha < 1$.

In the first case we simply get the whole real axis which is a closed set, in the second case we get all points with $x \leq 1$ and in the last case the empty set. Im pretty sure the real axis and all points with $x \leq 1$ are closed sets, however isnt the empty set defined to be open? Iam confused here. (closed set is a set for which every limit point of the set is in the set itself)

Comment: The empty set fulfills every definition which starts with "For every point in this set". Therefore it is closed (and open too, it is both). But you could also argue that the complement of the empty set is open.

Comment: The empty set is both open and closed.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Thank you, so its what we call a "clopen" set? For my other 2 cases, how can this be proved? I rather consider it as trivial.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \emptyset = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R} \;{\rm (complement \;of \;open \;set)}$$

Comment: So this means that the set $\mathbb{R}$ is also a clopen set?

Comment: I guess so. The complement "argument" ($\mathbb{R}$ is the complement of the open empty set), boundaries are empty etc. There is more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ is clopen as well.